# Laravel Nova resource resolve Using not working with belongs to

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

We have a very simple format to show a field in upper case.

```
BelongsTo::make('State')
    ->resolveUsing(function ($name) {
        return strtoupper($name);
    }),
```

Works fine on a Text::make field, but not BelongsTo::make. Checked all the usual places, but can't find any reference to it. Is there a different way to accomplish this or should resolveUsing or displayUsing work there?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, ust had to change resolveUsing to displayUsing and specify the column in the return

```
            BelongsTo::make('State')
            ->displayUsing(function ($state) {
                return strtoupper($state->abbreviation);
            }),
```